# UnsupportedOperationException when trying to add to List, only if not cast to Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an odd UnsupportedOperationException when trying to add to a List.

The code I have is as follows:

```
if( map.containsKey(c)){
    map.get(c).add(b);
} else {
    temp = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    temp.add(b);
    map.put(c, temp);
}
```

List is a HashMap with a List as values.

When I run this code, which naturally is iterated in loops, I get an UnsupportedOperation Exception.

If I change it to:

```
List<ArrayList> list = (ArrayList<MyClass>) map.get(c);
list.add(b);
```

I don't gt an exception.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Please show a minimal *complete* example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

While defining the `List` of `Map` , define it as

```
List<Map<String, ArrayList<MyClass>>>
```

instead of

```
List<Map<String, List<MyClass>>>
```

**OR**

Typecast the `List` to `ArrayList`

```
((ArrayList<MyClass>)map.get(c)).add(b);
```

Not every `List` implementation supports the `add()` method.Please refer to the [List#add() API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) documentation, which clearly says **UnsupportedOperationException** - *if the add operation is not supported by this list*.

Comment: Edited. Please see the response.

Comment: I see, but in this case we _know_ that the List is an ArrayList. How would casting change anything here? (And I'm going to delete my wrong comment above to avoid confusing people)

Comment: Well, about interface you are correct, but what if I implement a `List` and override the `add()` method as : `public boolean add(Object e) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(""); }`

Comment: *but in this case we know that the List is an ArrayList.* Where did the OP mentioned it is an `ArrayList` ?

Comment: Quote: `temp = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    temp.add(b);
    map.put(c, temp);`

Comment: That's not part of the original post.

Comment: It's in the `else` part of the posted code, which I copied very close to the posting of the question to try to reproduce the problem. Anyways, I was just confused as to why I would have to cast a List to an ArrayList to add values. (This is going chatty, so I'll leave now.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing *seems* impossible.

The typecast in `List<ArrayList> list = (ArrayList<MyClass>) map.get(c);` should make no difference to the method that is called when you call `add`.  That's not how method overriding works!  (There is only one `add` method with one argument, so you can't be affecting overload resolution with that typecast.)

Also it makes no sense that `add` on a list that you can cast to `ArrayList` would throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.  (It is theoretically possible ... but you'd need to have created a subclass of `ArrayList` for that to happen.  And surely you'd know that you had done that ... and you'd have told us!)

The best explanation I can think of is that:

- the typecast is failing with an exception (which is what I'd have expected ... since my guess is that you've got an "unmodifiable" wrapper class here), and
- you are not noticing that exception because it is being "squashed".

(Other possible explanations are that you've misread the stacktrace, you are running "stale" code that hasn't been rebuilt properly, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast the Map value into a ArrayList before doing add call, something like `((ArrayList<MyClass>)(map.get(c))).add(b);`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
map.get(c).add(b);
```

to:

```
System.out.println(map.get(c).getClass());
map.get(c).add(b);
```

Is it really an ArrayList that you have?